# C# ShowDialog() doesn't block main form when triggered from thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application with a main form and several background threads. In order to show "nice" messages I implemented a form to be shown as a modal dialog using `ShowDialog()`.

All of the calls to `ShowDialog()` are implemented on form level of the main form (and not on thread level), but sometimes I trigger an event from a thread which will be handled on form level of the main form. In those cases, the dialog is no longer modal ... the main form is not blocked. When the call to `ShowDialog()` is not triggered from a thread, it is modal as required.

How can I make sure that every call to ShowDialog() will block the main form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I make sure that every call to `ShowDialog()` will block the main form?

Execute the calls to `ShowDialog()` on the main thread. If you need to invoke them from a different thread, use `Invoke()` to run them on the main thread.

Comment: can you please give an example on how to use `Invoke()` instead of `ShowDialog()`

Comment: @devnull69 Google can give you a few hundreds of thousands of examples of how to use `Invoke`.

Comment: Indeed. For instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks to all, I think I got it. Simply using `handler.Invoke(...)` instead of just `handler(...)` from inside the thread did the trick

Comment: Pitty from High-rep users, to give such answer "google to find the example". or link to the code-rot page.

Comment: @T.Todua I think that independent research is important. Do you not? And what is stack overflow if not a repository of information that ca be searched? That's the entire MO for the site.